# Animation glitch when adding rows and UITableViewHeaderFooterView height is UITableViewAutomaticDimension

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitableviewsectionheader, uitableviewautomaticdimension

I am experiencing some animation glitches when insert new rows in a section and height for header is set to be UITableViewAutomaticDimension with an estimated height. Also, as you may notice, when deleting the rows the headers are jumping directly to the final position.

[image]

On the other hand, glitch disappears if estimated is set to 0 (which means no estimation), but height of header is not computed properly.

[image]

Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

Since I got any answer, and after doing some research in the documentation, I can conclude this is a limitation on the SDK. If I calculate the needed height using:

```
[header.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:
                  withHorizontalFittingPriority:
                        verticalFittingPriority:];
```

rather the automaticDimension, it works fine and no glitch appears.